# Please fix the "new activity" banner

Tags: feature-request, css

This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

The bar is grey. It looks quite bad with the nice beige theme we've got going on, so I request that either the colour be changed to something less hideous ([maybe rainbow](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3797298#3797298)) or that it is removed entirely, along with the little (1) in the `<title>`.

Answer (score 2):

Take it away! Thankfully I do not see it yet, but it looks awfully distracting. Or at least make it optional. Actually, many more things should be made option, like adding a break line that shows where comments are "abridged", etc.